# Bootstrap modal not closing after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I believe I will get a solution here, bootstrap modal does not disappear after form submission. **I only want to make bootstrap modal disappear after form submission and when again button is clicked (without refreshing the page) form should open, send data and modal should disappears and so on...** This is it !

Here is a bootstrap modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade myPopup" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal_dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Board</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="create_Category_board" id="myform">
          <input type="text" 
                 id="customInput"
                 class="board_name"
                 name="board[name]"
                 placeholder="Board Name ..." />
          <input type="text"
                 class="board_description"
                 name="board[description]"
                 placeholder="Board Description ..." />
          <input type="hidden"
                 class="board_description"
                 id="myCid"
                 name="board[category_id]" />
          <input type="submit" value="Create Board" class="ShowFormButton"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My form is bound with backbone JS function:

```js
events: {

    "submit form.create_Category_board": "createCategoryBoard"
  },

  createCategoryBoard: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var that = this;

    // get form attrs, reset form
    var $form = $(event.target);
    var attrs = $form.serializeJSON();

    $form[0].reset();

    var board = new Kanban.Models.Board();

    // fail if no board name
    if (!attrs.board.name) {
      var $createContainer = $("div.create_board");
      var $nameInput = that.$el.find("input.board_name");

      $createContainer.effect("shake", {
        distance: 9,
        times: 2,
        complete: function() {
          $nameInput.show();
          $nameInput.focus();
        }
      }, 350);
      return false;
    }

    attrs.board.category_id = myid;
    var category = Kanban.categories.get(myid);
    var boards = category.get("assigned_boards");
    // save list
    board.save(attrs.board, {
      success: function(data) {
        board.get("users").add(Kanban.currentUser);

        boards.add(board);

        // keep focus on list input
        that.$el.find("input.board_name").focus();

      }
    });
    $('#basicModal').modal('hide');
  }
```

As a last line in above function I have tried most popular solution `$('#basicModal').modal('hide');` available on web! It makes my modal look like this:

[image: modal]

i.e. it not hides the modal, moreover make screen black and change the direction of bootstrap modal from center of screen to little right. May be it is overridden by CSS of JS. But I am not sure.

Comment: Can you make a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't know how to include backbone code in plnkr !

Comment: Just upload all the files by creating new files.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have added it on plnkr. Can you see it: http://plnkr.co/edit/YIjF32ojGVHslrnwr5ZP?p=preview . I am not much familiar with with this tool ! I think i have missed some thing again !

Comment: Hey @EM923 Does it work like how it works in your home?

Comment: Check this out? http://plnkr.co/edit/XkRNIjl8T3kg3e8m27HW?p=preview

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am not sure ! Actually this is a part of a large application which is linked with each other strongly. That is why I am unable to post a lot of code on public ! Can you please provide some suggestion by this above question ! If you need some more info I will provide it. I need this done ASAP ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @PraveenKumar check your email !

Comment: Gotcha! I got the mail!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have this code online which is working fine, I don't know what is wrong in my case ! http://www.bootply.com/NabeelNazir/KhQdoNQzb2

Comment: @PraveenKumar any suggestion ?

Comment: Let's take it offline buddy. Need to connect with you in remote to check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting my own answer because if some one needs a quicker help, then may be it is helpful: 
Just replace: `$('#basicModal').modal('hide');` with this line:

`$(".modal-header button").click();` which is last line of my `JS` function. 
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that div.modal-backdrop remains after you hide the modal,
you can see it in developer tools.Try simple remove
`$('#basicModal').modal('hide');` 
`$('.modal-backdrop').remove();`

Cheers

Comment: what happened when I click again to open modal (without refreshing page) ? It will not appear because it has been removed ! How to make it appear again in DOM ?